# Generating random samples that satisfies specific r-squared of MAPE

Tags: sampling, simulation, r-squared, mape

I would like to generate some samples that satisfies a specific **r-squared** or **MAPE(Mean Absolute Percentage Error)** with a given vector.

For example, a vector **a_i is given** and I want to **generate some vector b_i
that guarantee corr(a_i, b_i) = n or MAPE(a_i, b_i) = m. (n, m is specific value that are given.)**

I know there are infinite vector b_i, but want to know if there is a systematic way to randomly generate them.